# Security Advisory: GHSA-cfjv-5498-mph5 actionview (RubyGems)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, rubygems, actionview

Recently I got a mail from GitHub with the the following Security advisory.
Its say:

we found a vulnerable dependency in repositories you have security alert access to.
Security Advisory GHSA-cfjv-5498-mph5

Rails version: 6.0.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some RnD and check attached link in mail. I get this issue is related to Action View's translation helpers.

This issue is occur `When an HTML-unsafe string is passed as the default for a missing translation key named html or ending in _html`

To fix this I update my rails version from `6.0.3.2` to `6.0.3.3`

If you don't want to update your Rails version you can fix its impact by manually escaping default translations with the html_escape helper (aliased as h):

`<%= t("welcome_html", default: h(untrusted_user_controlled_string)) %>`

This issue is occurring at action_view version `>= 6.0.0.0, <= 6.0.3.2 and <= 5.2.4.3`
Resolved at `6.0.3.3 and 5.2.4.4`

Reference: https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-cfjv-5498-mph5